# Android CheckedTextView how to update the view

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I have programmatically added CheckedTextView to the linearlayout view. Please look at following code:

```
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private CheckedTextView checkedtextview;
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.statusView);
    checkedtextview = new CheckedTextView(ScanStatus.this, null, android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple);
    checkedtextview.setText(R.string.applications);
    linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

Later in code I have to update the checkedtextview like below:

```
checkedtextview.setCheckMarkDrawable(getDrawable(R.mipmap.check1));
checkedtextview.setChecked(true);
checkedtextview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

But this results in crash with following log:

D/AndroidRuntime(24818): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(24818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24818): Process: com.example.ashwini.timapp, PID: 24818
E/AndroidRuntime(24818): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Please suggest me how can I update the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First, if you have a reference to your checkedtextview all the time - you can update it without calling addView:

```
    checkedtextview.setCheckMarkDrawable(getDrawable(R.mipmap.check1));
checkedtextview.setChecked(true);
checkedtextview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);.
```

In the second case use tip from @坚持远方 answer:

```
    linearLayout.removeView(checkedtextview);
checkedtextview.setCheckMarkDrawable(getDrawable(R.mipmap.check1));
checkedtextview.setChecked(true); 
checkedtextview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); 
linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

Comment: Let me know if first variant doesn't work. Maybe you also need to call 'checkedtextview.invalidate()'

Comment: I am beginner to android. How to have reference to checkedtextview? Can you please explain with the code snippet?

Comment: You already have it as I see. It's your private variable inside your class. Once you created it at the start - you have a reference and don't have to recreate it each time to update. You can change properties of this view everywhere in you class in runtime and maybe should call `invalidate()` method to redraw it on the screen

Answer (score 2):

i think first you need removed the view,then update it.

```
linearLayout.removeView(checkedtextview);
checkedtextview.setCheckMarkDrawable(getDrawable(R.mipmap.check1));
checkedtextview.setChecked(true); 
checkedtextview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); 
linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to add the `checkedtextview` twice.

To change the checked status, you can get the view from `linearLayout` like below

Either `linearLayout.getChildAt(position)` 
or 
keep a reference of `checkedtextview` in your class and change the status whenever you want.

Comment: I am new to android, Can you please explain with the code?

Answer (score 0):

you can put check

```
  if (checkedtextview.getParent() == null) {
        // thn add your childview
    } else {
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        //add your child view herer
    }
```

or if you don't wanna remove all child from parent thn you can try this :

```
 if (checkedtextview.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup)checkedtextview.getParent()).removeView(checkedtextview);
    linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

Comment: Won't work. This would remove all views from this layout. And also null check is not correct, if parent is null you can't add views, there would be NPE.

Comment: if (checkedtextview.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup)checkedtextview.getParent()).removeView(checkedtextview);
        linearLayout.addView(checkedtextview);